# JLabel automatically centers it self inside GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a custom `JTextField` that hosts a `JLabel`, So I have wrapped the `JTextField` and the `JLabel` in a custom Class that extends `JPanel`

The `JPanel` layout is set to GridBagLayout since I only need place 2 components vertically. Here is how it looks like

[image]

This is the code, I can't spot where I have instructed the GridBagLayout to center the JLabel.

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
jLabel = new JLabel();
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
gbc.gridy = 1;
add(jLabel, gbc);
```

[image]

I want to have the JLabel the same position at shown in the GIF. How can I achieve this? Would also be nice if anyone can point what the exact text size would look good on the JLabel.

Comment: Set the [anchor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#anchor) in your GridBagConstraints.

Comment: @VGR, I tried to make anchor use PAGE_START but it did not work. Forgot to put it in the post. Will edit Thanks! :)

Comment: Ah alright I see, Theres a LINE_STARTS attribute @VGR thanks.

Comment: `layout is set to GridBagLayout since I only need place 2 components vertically.` - or you could use a vertical BoxLayout. You would also need to set the alignmentX to 0.0 to make sure each component is left justified in the box.

Comment: @camickr I have tried to use BoxLayout after your suggestion but the JLabel does not start from line start, nor is it center. It's kinda in between, How would I resolve this?

Comment: @SamzSakerz, see example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the JLabel does not start from line start, nor is it center. It's kinda in between

I'm not sure what your exact code is and how you nest the custom panel in another panel.

But as I mentioned above when you have weird alignment you need to make sure each component has the same x alignment so they can be aligned the same way.

I can't reproduce your problem using the simple example below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    SSCCE()
    {
        JPanel box = new JPanel();
        box.setLayout( new BoxLayout(box, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS) );
        box.setBorder( new LineBorder(Color.RED) );

        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        //textField.setAlignmentX(JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        System.out.println( textField.getAlignmentX() );
        box.add( textField );


        JLabel label = new JLabel("Some text");
        System.out.println( label.getAlignmentX() );
        box.add( label );

        add( box );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

But as you can see from the output by default a text field has center alignment and the label left alignment. Try making them both left aligned.

Comment: Ah I see, I am having the same problem as that.

Comment: making the `lynxTextField` left fixed. I was trying to set the `jLabel` to left, But I don't think I can achieve the animation shown in the GIF using a BoxLayout? Or what Layout would be the best for the exact results

Comment: I'm not sure why the animation would be any different? Neither layout manager supports animation. So you need to fake the layout by manually setting the location until the component reaches its final position. Based on your gif I thought you had that process working, so it should be the same.

Comment: I don't have the animation working, But I am assuming I would need to start the label at the center of the JTextField and work my way down, but `setLocation` has no effect on the JLabel.

Comment: I have accepted your answer since I am going on with the box layout, I will ask about the animation in a different question after my attempts.

Comment: No, it is much more involved than that. The size of the panel would initially be determined by the size of the text field. Or the size of the panel would need to be fixed assuming the two components are displayed vertically (but this would seem to waste vertical space if you do this for all text fields). Then as the label is moved vertically the height of the panel will need to change dynamically every time the label is moved. This would mean all the other custom panels would also need to shift as the animation progresses.

Comment: You might be able to use the [Drag Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/) to help you with this process. It was originally designed to dynamically recalculated the preferred size of the panel are components are manually dragged. In your case you don't have a manually drag, but an animated drag.

Comment: Ah alright, After seeing your comments I am gonna leave the animation alone for now since It looks complex.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `VGR` in the comments, I have solved this issue by setting the anchor to `LINE_STARTS`

```
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_STARTS;
```

Edit: Ended up using BoxLayout thanks to `camickr` for answering with an example.